# IntelliJ 11 - Can't delete module? (Mac)

Tags: intellij-idea

How do you delete modules from projects in IntelliJ on a Mac? Normal delete doesn't work and the context menu doesn't show a delete option?

[Switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ a few days ago]

*edit*

Module was originally checked out from SVN if that makes any difference?

*edit*

Sorry I was being stupid, deleting is done with fn + backspace not cmd + backspace (for Macs without the Del key).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Open `Project Structure` | `Modules` and press the `[-]` button to remove the selected module.

Comment: Thanks, that worked :) Strange there isn't a context menu option for this.

Comment: There is no menu, but you can use `Del` keyboard shortcut in the Project View.

Comment: Ah ok, my Mac is one without the Del key. In any case, thanks for the help.

Comment: to be clear: File -> Project Structure opens a new dialog window. Under Project Settings click on Modules. That will show the list of modules in the project. The [-] button is above the list of modules.

Comment: I have odd behavior on my PC with this.  I have two projects both which contain the same module.  If I do the [-] thing under project structure, even though the other project is not open it will end up removing it from *both* projects (!) somethign is weird here.

Comment: Not helping for me, even after deleting I have reopened the same window and it was there.

Comment: This doesn't work for my situation, hitting the '-' button does nothing. I successfully deleted the module from the project, and all of the files are gone, but the module still shows up in the project structure dialog and stubbornly refuses to delete